# Equivalent avro record data for map type

Tags: python-2.7, avro

I have a avro schema as below, I want an example/sample record for the schema.

Schema:

```
{
   "name" : "root",
   "type" : "record",
   "fields" : [
      {
         "name" : "sub_rec",
         "type" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
               "type" : "map",
               "values" : "string"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried like below, but it does not work

```
{
    "sub_rec" : {[
        "key1" : "val1",
        "key2" : "val2"
    ]}
}
```

Comment: `sub-rec` vs `sub_rec`. Also, it is an array, not an object/map

Comment: do you mean the record should be like this?
{
    "sub_rec" : [{[
        "key1" : "val1",
        "key2" : "val2"
    ]}]
}

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with Avro, but I do know that this is not valid as arrays can't have key-value pairs

```
[
    "key1" : "val1",
    "key2" : "val2"
]
```

Here's my thought process on the correct record format.

You start with a record. I don't think the name applies here, but if it did, that might need to be the name of the class that you are serializing against.

`{}`

Inside of that, there is a field named `sub_rec` whose type is an array.

`{ "sub_rec" : [] }`

Within that array field, you have items that are map types with values that are strictly strings.

```
{
    "sub_rec" : [
        { "key1" : "value" }, 
        { "key2" : "value" }
    ]
}
```

---

Alternative explanation (going backwards)

You have a map record with values of only strings

```
{ "key" : "string-value" }
```

These are stored in an array

```
[ { "key1" : "string-value" }, { "key2" : "string-value" } ]
```

That array is stored in a record with the name `"sub_rec"`

(Same as full record above)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but it did not work.

Comment: Are you sure that you can have a nested type? Like you have `"type" : { "type": ... } }`?

Comment: My answer seems to works when [converted to a JSON schema](https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/avro.jsp) then [validated in JSON](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)

Comment: I have used the python program provided in the avro's official webpage to test - [link](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedpython.html#Serializing+and+deserializing+without+code+generation). And for compiling the schema to see if it is correct, I am using the avro-tools jar provided in the avro's official page ([link](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html#Compiling+the+schema))

Comment: Even if I logically go inside-to-out of your schema, I still can't find why this is incorrect

Comment: And, I think, JSON schema is different from Avro schema as Avro supports many complex types. Not a 100% sure.

Comment: Yeah, even I am trying to figure out what is the problem with my data.

Comment: I understand Avro supports complex types, but it was meant to be interoperable with already existing JSON libraries. And those complex types have a direct [JSON mapping](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#schema_complex)